# Cheap way to turn covariance matrix in tensorflow to correlation matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have tensor of shape [N,d,d] of N covariance matrices and I would like to turn them into correlation matrices. Is there any cheap implementation in tensorflow / keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the correlation matrix, so all you need to do is divide each element of that matrix by the appropriate standard deviation product.
These standard deviations are present on your matrix's diagonals, and can be efficiently retrieved with a few matrix multiplications (more about the math [on this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Relation_to_the_correlation_matrix)):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def to_corr(cov):
    d_inv = tf.linalg.diag(1/tf.sqrt(tf.abs(tf.linalg.diag_part(cov))))
    corr = d_inv @ cov @ d_inv
    return corr
```

Sanity check:

```py
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

x = tf.random.normal(shape=(3,5,3))
cov_matrix = tfp.stats.covariance(x, sample_axis=0, event_axis=-1)
tf.debugging.assert_near(to_corr(cov_matrix),tfp.stats.correlation(x, sample_axis=0, event_axis=-1))
```